# Appending key,value pair to my JSON data

Tags: javascript, json

This is my JSON response

```
{
    "PatientSearchResult": {
        "Patient": [{
            "AccountBalanceCalcMethod": 2,
            "AlternatePatientID": 0,
            "AssignmentOfBenifits": 0,
            "CellPhoneNumber1": null,
            "CellPhoneNumber2": null,
            "Citizenship": 0,
            "Credential": 0,
            "DateOfBirth": null,
            "Deceased": 0,
            "DeceasedDate": "\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/",
            "DoesPatientHaveResidentProof": false,
            "DriversLicenseNumber": null,
            "DriversLicenseState": 0,
            "EmailAddress1": null,
            "EmailAddress2": null,
            "Enabled": false,
            "Ethnicity": 0,
            "Firstname": "2914 FirstName"
        }, {
            "AccountBalanceCalcMethod": 2,
            "AlternatePatientID": 0,
            "AssignmentOfBenifits": 0,
            "CellPhoneNumber1": null,
            "CellPhoneNumber2": null,
            "Citizenship": 0,
            "Credential": 0,
            "DateOfBirth": "\/Date(378709200000-0500)\/",
            "Deceased": 0,
            "DeceasedDate": "\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/",
            "DoesPatientHaveResidentProof": false,
            "DriversLicenseNumber": null,
            "DriversLicenseState": 0,
            "EmailAddress1": null,
            "EmailAddress2": null,
            "Enabled": false,
            "Ethnicity": 0,
            "Firstname": "4261 FirstName"
            }, {
            "AccountBalanceCalcMethod": 2,
            "AlternatePatientID": 0,
            "AssignmentOfBenifits": 0,
            "CellPhoneNumber1": null,
            "CellPhoneNumber2": null,
            "Citizenship": 0,
            "Credential": 0,
            "DateOfBirth": "\/Date(1136264400000-0500)\/",
            "Deceased": 0,
            "DeceasedDate": "\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/",
            "DoesPatientHaveResidentProof": false,
            "DriversLicenseNumber": null,
            "DriversLicenseState": 0,
            "EmailAddress1": null,
            "EmailAddress2": null,
            "Enabled": false,
            "Ethnicity": 0,
            "Firstname": "Bo"
            }, {
            "AccountBalanceCalcMethod": 2,
            "AlternatePatientID": 0,
            "AssignmentOfBenifits": 0,
            "CellPhoneNumber1": null,
            "CellPhoneNumber2": null,
            "Citizenship": 0,
            "Credential": 0,
            "DateOfBirth": "\/Date(-2192126400000-0400)\/",
            "Deceased": 0,
            "DeceasedDate": "\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/",
            "DoesPatientHaveResidentProof": false,
            "DriversLicenseNumber": null,
            "DriversLicenseState": 0,
            "EmailAddress1": null,
            "EmailAddress2": null,
            "Enabled": false,
            "Ethnicity": 0,
            "Firstname": "Mark"
           }, {
            "AccountBalanceCalcMethod": 2,
            "AlternatePatientID": 0,
            "AssignmentOfBenifits": 0,
            "CellPhoneNumber1": null,
            "CellPhoneNumber2": null,
            "Citizenship": 0,
            "Credential": 0,
            "DateOfBirth": "\/Date(-381697200000-0500)\/",
            "Deceased": 0,
            "DeceasedDate": "\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/",
            "DoesPatientHaveResidentProof": false,
            "DriversLicenseNumber": null,
            "DriversLicenseState": 0,
            "EmailAddress1": null,
            "EmailAddress2": null,
            "Enabled": false,
            "Ethnicity": 0,
            "Firstname": "Scott"
            }, {
            "AccountBalanceCalcMethod": 2,
            "AlternatePatientID": 0,
            "AssignmentOfBenifits": 0,
            "CellPhoneNumber1": null,
            "CellPhoneNumber2": null,
            "Citizenship": 0,
            "Credential": 0,
            "DateOfBirth": "\/Date(-445806000000-0500)\/",
            "Deceased": 0,
            "DeceasedDate": "\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/",
            "DoesPatientHaveResidentProof": false,
            "DriversLicenseNumber": null,
            "DriversLicenseState": 0,
            "EmailAddress1": null,
            "EmailAddress2": null,
            "Enabled": false,
            "Ethnicity": 0,
            "Firstname": "John"
            }, {
            "AccountBalanceCalcMethod": 2,
            "AlternatePatientID": 0,
            "AssignmentOfBenifits": 0,
            "CellPhoneNumber1": null,
            "CellPhoneNumber2": null,
            "Citizenship": 0,
            "Credential": 0,
            "DateOfBirth": "\/Date(-880830000000-0500)\/",
            "Deceased": 0,
            "DeceasedDate": "\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/",
            "DoesPatientHaveResidentProof": false,
            "DriversLicenseNumber": null,
            "DriversLicenseState": 0,
            "EmailAddress1": null,
            "EmailAddress2": null,
            "Enabled": false,
            "Ethnicity": 0,
            "Firstname": "Dagwood"                
        }, {
            "AccountBalanceCalcMethod": 2,
            "AlternatePatientID": 0,
            "AssignmentOfBenifits": 0,
            "CellPhoneNumber1": null,
            "CellPhoneNumber2": null,
            "Citizenship": 0,
            "Credential": 0,
            "DateOfBirth": null,
            "Deceased": 0,
            "DeceasedDate": "\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/",
            "DoesPatientHaveResidentProof": false,
            "DriversLicenseNumber": null,
            "DriversLicenseState": 0,
            "EmailAddress1": null,
            "EmailAddress2": null,
            "Enabled": false,
            "Ethnicity": 0,
            "Firstname": "Clyde"
            }, {
            "AccountBalanceCalcMethod": 2,
            "AlternatePatientID": 0,
            "AssignmentOfBenifits": 0,
            "CellPhoneNumber1": null,
            "CellPhoneNumber2": null,
            "Citizenship": 0,
            "Credential": 0,
            "DateOfBirth": "\/Date(-249678000000-0500)\/",
            "Deceased": 0,
            "DeceasedDate": "\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/",
            "DoesPatientHaveResidentProof": false,
            "DriversLicenseNumber": null,
            "DriversLicenseState": 0,
            "EmailAddress1": null,
            "EmailAddress2": null,
            "Enabled": false,
            "Ethnicity": 0,
            "Firstname": "Fred"
            }]
    }
}
```

I am trying to parse it like this.

```
function SortByName(x,y) {        
  return ((x.LastName == y.LastName) ? 
      0 : ((x.LastName > y.LastName) ? 1 : -1 ));    
}   

function RenderPatientSearchData(PatientSearchResponse){
    var PatientSearchData = JSON.parse(PatientSearchResponse);
    var results = PatientSearchData['PatientSearchResult'];
    results.Patient.sort(SortByName);
    for (i = 0, len = results.PatientSearchResult.Patient.length; i < len; i++) {
        // some code here
    }
    //....
}
```

How can i append key,value pair to my JSON. I want to append

```
Header:'somevalue'
```

how would i append a Header label to first items of each data. some like which will make me differentiate that these are A Names , these are B Names...

You can see a sample response of the data in this link... something like this

https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/raw/master/Resources/examples/table_view_headers.js

Comment: That's not JSON, that's just a JavaScript object.

Comment: To be more precise: The first is JSON, but `PatientSearchData` is a JS object. So do you want to change the JSON or add properties to `PatientSearchData`?

Comment: add properties to my PatientSearchData... i am using results object... so its a JS Object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty simple if you want to add properties to a Javascript object (as opposed to manipulating a JSON string).  Wherever you want to add 'Header': 'somevalue' just do:

```
PatientSearchData.Header = 'somevalue';
```

Comment: How can i add it to certain objects.. and certain object should not contain Header

Comment: @John - it could be something like `PatientSearchData.Patient[0].Header = 'somevalue';`  Just treat it like a normal JS object.  [This article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html) on JS objects as associative arrays should help you understand the whole topic more.

Comment: But how can i add this... new Header... and where.. i am confused

Comment: @John - where are you trying to add it to?  Without knowing what object Header is to be a property of I can't tell you where it goes.  It doesn't quite work like `new Header()` unless you have created a `Header()` object.  Are you familiar with Javascript's version of object orientation?

Comment: I want to add it to certain properties this header:'A' to group my Json Strings... or how would i create a new property header:'a' and add it to my Object after parsing it

Comment: @John - where in the object do you want to add it?  The syntax is literally what I've shown - to add a new property just do `.propertyName = propertyValue` in Javascript.  It's that simple.  [This example](http://jsfiddle.net/BLLUD/) taken loosely from the code you provided might help you.